# Overriding parent methods gotcha

Tags: php

Why does the code below:

```
class A {   
    public function foo() {}
}

class B extends A { 
    private function foo() {}
}
```

generates an fatal error while this:

```
class A {
    private function foo() {}   
}

class B extends A {
    public function foo() {}    
}
```

doesn't although the documentation says "If the child doesn't see the parent's private methods, the child can't override them"?

Comment: And what's said in fatal error? Seems you're mixing your examples. Since first one works perfectly and second one generates error as `B::foo` should be public too.

Comment: I've corrected my question so can You answer it now?

Answer (score 1):

So let's analyze what you have:

```
class A {
    private function foo() {}   
}

class B extends A {
    public function foo() {}    
}
```

Here class **A** has a private method, and since it's private it's not seen in class **B**. So in class **B** you can create method with the **same name**. It's not overriding, it's just creating method with the same name.

And in this example:

```
class A {   
    public function foo() {}
}

class B extends A { 
    private function foo() {}
}
```

Method `A::foo` is public and you can override it in class **B**. But as it's `public`, visibility of children method shouldn't be stricter then parent one. So you can't have `B::foo` as `private`, only `public`.

Answer (score 0):

It is all about semantic. In first example in **method foo of class B** you can call parent **method foo of class A** using **parent::foo()**, but he is a private.